# Get item from GSI but got "The provided key element does not match the schema"

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have AWS DynamoDB table with `ref1, ref2, and ref3` at last column like this
[image: columns]

Here is overview
[image: overview]

I am trying to [get a record](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.01) in AWS DynamoDB with `ref1, ref2, and ref3` as a composite key
[image: GSI]

```js
  params = {
    TableName: process.env.PAYMENT_DB_TRANSACTION,
    Key: {
      "ref1": billPaymentRef1,
      "ref2": billPaymentRef2,
      "ref3": billPaymentRef3
    }
  };
  console.log(params);
  docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
  });
```

I confirm that `params` is correct

```js
{
  TableName: 'payment-th-stg-v2-op-transaction',
  Key: { ref1: 'REF1', ref2: 'REF2', ref3: 'REF3' }
}
```

Here is the error

```js
Unable to read item. Error JSON: {
  "message": "The provided key element does not match the schema",
  "code": "ValidationException",
  "time": "2020-01-03T12:17:39.090Z",
  "requestId": "PDC6A7N22Q8BT789H3K2I1N9VNVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 48.839609039271245
}
```

**Question:**
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to query the item using primary key which in your case is the partition key + sort key: requestId + countryCode.

Comment: That's sad. Because I really need them